# How can I combine two mysql queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to combine these two queries into one:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (name, parent) VALUES ('$name', '$parent')");

mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET child='$child' WHERE ID = $id");
```

Can it be done?

Comment: These are two distinct operations - why are you trying to combine them?

Comment: @ thetaiko this is for a script that will create a new subcategory category item. When a sub category is inserted I'm trying to get that sub category's id to be inserted in the parent category's child field.

Comment: so `$child` is the auto generated ID from the `INSERT` and `$id == $parent`?

Comment: @ thetaiko so $child is the auto generated ID from the INSERT  and $id == $parent - That is Correct.

Comment: You could also make a stored procedure to do this for you.  It would then be called from one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know if this fits your problem, in fact it is possible to combine multiple queries into one, by using the [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) extension (it will not work with mysql extension)

```
mysqli_multi_query($connection, "INSERT INTO a (attrib1, attrib2) VALUES ('$a', '$b');UPDATE b SET attrib3='$c' WHERE attrib4 = $d");
```

Comment: This is still running two queries - just sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger in MySQL.

Without doing any checking on if a parent category exists, or catching exceptions the following should do the trick.  Replace 'dbname' with whatever your db is.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `dbname`.`update_parent`//
CREATE TRIGGER `dbname`.`categories` AFTER INSERT ON `dbname`.`categories`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE categories SET child = NEW.ID WHERE ID = NEW.parent;
END
//
```

When the trigger is functioning correctly, the update will get called automatically after an `INSERT` so all you have to do is run:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (name, parent) VALUES ('$name', '$parent')");
```